# Writing data (structure) to file

Tags: c

Well, I have a function:

```
CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO *pPriKeyInfo = NULL;
DWORD cbPriKeyInfo = 0;
SxKS_ExportPKCS8_PriKeyInfo(
            pKey,
            &pPriKeyInfo,
            &cbPriKeyInfo);
```

which exports storage key (private key) into private key in specific structure:

```
typedef struct _CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO{
    DWORD                       Version;
    CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER  Algorithm;
    CRYPT_DER_BLOB              PrivateKey;
    PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTES           pAttributes;
}  CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO, *PCRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO;
```

I need to write data in this structure to the file:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("c:\\CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO.pem", "wb");
fwrite(&pPriKeyInfo, sizeof(pPriKeyInfo), cbPriKeyInfo, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

question is that, am I doing it right? because I think I am getting wrong data.

Comment: Your structure contains a pointer (which is hard to see because of Microsoft's asinine `P` typedefs). Pointers point to data *in memory* - it makes no sense to write a pointer to disk.

Comment: So, you say that this structure is pointer, if so, is it possible to get data and write it to file which this structure points ? (if i understand you correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fwrite(&pPriKeyInfo, sizeof(pPriKeyInfo), cbPriKeyInfo, fp);
```

The first three arguments of your call to `fwrite()` are incorrect. They tell `fwrite()` what to write in the file, so there is no doubt why the data stored in the file doesn't look good.

#### How to use the `fwrite()` function, in general

The first argument of [`fwrite()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) is a pointer to the data to be written. `fwrite()` can write an array of objects and its first argument is the address of the first object to write.

`pPriKeyInfo` is itself a pointer to the data you want to write in the file. Passing `&pPriKeyInfo` to `fwrite()` doesn't make any sense. You don't care about the value of `pPriKeyInfo` but to the data it points to.

The second argument of `fwrite()` is the size of each object to be written in the file. It should be the size of the structure pointed by the first argument (`CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO`).

The third argument of `fwrite()` is the number of objects to write. In your example it should be `1`.

All in all, the call to `fwrite()` should look like:

```
fwrite(pPriKeyInfo, sizeof(CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO), 1, fp);
```

#### But wait, it still doesn't save the correct data!

The explanation above assumes the object passed as the first argument to `fwrite()` (a struct of type [`CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381448(v=vs.85).aspx)) contains the actual data you want to write in the file.

This is not the case for [struct `CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381448(v=vs.85).aspx). This is its definition:

```
typedef struct _CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO {
  DWORD                      Version;
  CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER Algorithm;
  CRYPT_DER_BLOB             PrivateKey;
  CRYPT_ATTRIBUTES           *pAttributes;
} CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO, CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO, *PCRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO;
```

As you can see, the field `pAttributes` is a pointer to a [`CRYPT_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381146(v=vs.85).aspx) structure and the other two structure fields (`Algorithm` and `PrivateKey`) contain pointers themselves.

**This is definitely *not the correct way* to save a `CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO` structure in a file!** And from the large amount of pointers it contains I think this structure is designed to be used in memory, not to be saved.

It's not clear for me what exactly you want to save to the file but from the documentation it seems the actual key is stored in the `PrivateKey` member of the structure. To write it into the file you can use:

```
fwrite(pPriKeyInfo->PrivateKey.pbData, sizeof(BYTE), pPriKeyInfo->PrivateKey.cbData, fp);
```

Comment: Good explanation! You are partially right. Now I am getting private key itself [link](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#02202D816B2FBCE9886C563442DF10FB914FC14A3A05563E5394BB150F5C1209E4F6), but I need all the structure. like this: [link](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#3044020100301B06062A865C010703301106072A865C0107240006062A865C010709042202201177640858A94339A1A392726D6DF0FA3DF0B342D6505CDB802A5E810359B7F8)

Comment: may be I am not right, and I need to look somewhere else to get this type of data

Answer (score 1):

You're writing the *pointer* to the file. Pointers point to memory that is specific to the currently running process. If you load the pointer in another process, even one running the same program, then the pointer will not be valid.

So a quick-fix is to not write the pointer, but the *structure* to the file.

***However*** that will lead to the very same problem happening again, since one of the members in the structure is a pointer. What you need to do is to [*serialize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the structure.